# Can't set referer to localhost

Tags: php, curl

I have PHP script which need to generate playlist from stream links in specic url ($url).
So this url parsing and I get playlist with some strim links.
Like this

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:0,top_stream
http://link1
#EXTINF:0,tv123
http://link2
#EXTINF:0,music
http://link3
```

And this is part works on localhost and on hosting server.

When I upload whis script on my hosting server, and run script I get same playlist and I have same strim links in playlist.
BUT all links in playlist doesn't works - URL Link Not found.

Example
http://link1
http://link2 ... can't open - Not found

So I need to set referel to localhost in PHP file.

I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$url = "http://example.com".time();

$params = '';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://127.0.0.1/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$_data = json_decode($data, true);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Curl enabled and working on server.
Sorry for unclear post.
Thanks

Comment: _stream doesn' works._ - what doesn't works? what's the error message? You set the referer correctly (the url `"http://example.com".time();` isn't). _What's the problem_?

Comment: Make sure curl is enabled on your machine

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. This should be closed.

Comment: When open this link on browser error is "File not found"
When open this link in VLC player error is "URL can't open"
But on local host same link works. Sorry for unclear description.

Comment: 'http://127.0.0.1/' ?? wheres the file name